# Changing text in printf() based on value of a variable

Tags: c, printf

I haven't done C in a long while and slowly getting back into it. I made a small game and now going through 'bug-fixing' and making the odd tweak here and there. One issue I have if the text inside a `printf()` statement regarding turns ...

```
printf("CONGRATULATIONS!!\nYou won with %d turns remaining\n",turns);
```

Now that is great until `turns==1`.

Is there an efficient way to change the text 'turns' based on the condition of the turns variable? Or would I have to use if statements (one solution I already have but I'm sure there is a better one!)

```
if (turns==1)
{
  printf("CONGRATULATIONS!!\nYou won with %d turn remaining\n",turns);
}
else
{
  printf("CONGRATULATIONS!!\nYou won with %d turns remaining\n",turns);
}
```

Sorry for the really 'noob' question but I'm stuck as to what would be the most efficient way of doing this.

Comment: Be wary of internationalization (I18N), but with English, you could use a variant on `printf("Congratulations: You won with %d %s left\n", turns, (turns == 1) ? "turn" : "turns");`.  With I18N, you'd probably use two separate message strings — and worry about whether there are languages that treat other numbers than just 1 (vs anything else) differently.  Zero turns might be a problem case.  ISTR some languages with such interesting rules, but don't now remember which one(s).

Comment: Use the ternary operator.

Comment: Good point to consider, thanks. For now I'm not overly concerned about the internationalization issues whilst I try to remember what I did for a few weeks at university many years ago!

Comment: @JonathanLeffler [here be all the interesting rules for you to refresh your memory](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/Plural-forms.html). Matra you could use `gettext` if on glibc.

Comment: Thank you, @AnttiHaapala. While that wasn't the source I remembered, it covers more possibilities than I remembered. Properly done, I18N is hard.  (I note in passing that POSIX's [`printf()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html) family of functions use `n$` rather than `$n` when identifying parameter posisitions. The manual for `gettext` includes the example `printf(ngettext("%$2d file removed from directory %$1s", "%$2d files removed from directory %$1s", n), dir, n);` which should use `%1$s` instead of `%$1s` to conform to POSIX. Does it work with GNU?)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right and the document is wrong. Even gcc complains with `-Wformat`, and the output is `%$2d file removed from directory %$1s%`.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: I've just now reported the problem by email to the two mail addresses at the bottom of the page.  Thanks for checking/confirming that I'm right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using the [conditional-operator](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.15) might satisfy your needs

```
printf("CONGRATULATIONS!!\nYou won with %d turn%s remaining.\n", 
  turns, 
  turns==1 ?"" :"s");
```

or just do

```
printf("CONGRATULATIONS!!\nYou won with %d turn(s) remaining.\n",
  turns);
```

;-)

Comment: Excellent, the use of the true/false works just fine. I could have used the latter but I'm too much of a perfectionist to use turn(s) :-P

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Totally agree and that was a question I had when I started too..Sure your answer is ideal, thus I will upvote another answer of yours, I like.